# if statement not checking condition

Tags: c#, if-statement

My if below for some reason checks for the first but not the second condition.

The first it checks the user/passwd against a db and the second is a hard code user and passowrd.

When I enter the hard coded user/passwd, it doesn't let me thru, only using the db user/passwd.

Any idea what is wrong?

```
if ((userTxt == userDB && passwdTxt == passwdDB) ||
    (userTxt == "user" && passwdTxt == "test"))
{
    switch (frmMdiMain.loginPageText)
    {
        case "exit":
            mainPage.Hide();
            Application.Exit();
            break;
        case "internal":
            mdiInternalUse internUseForm = new mdiInternalUse();
            internUseForm.Show();
            this.Close();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: Is it possible that the input method you use give a `userTxt` and/or `passwdTxt` containing a newline/return character at the end?

Comment: I would suggest more context as well.  What are the types of these values? The switch in the middle can be removed as it isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: If it is Java (as it looks) try `"user".equals(userTxt)&&"test".equals(passwdTxt)` (see *[How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)*).

Answer (score 0):

Without the language you are using it is hard to answer, but I think the problem is that the value of `userTxt` and `passwdTxt` are compared to a different object than the one represented by `"user"` and `"test"`

For example in C/C++ of `userTxt` is a pointer to `char`, it will have a different addess than `"user".

In java, the `String` object holding the value of `userTxt` and `"user"` can also be different.

You will need to perform a proper comparison on the strings (e.g. `strcmp()` in C, use `sts::string` in C++, use `userTxt.compare("user")` in java)

Comment: Sorry, it is C# and is a the variables are string

Comment: C# is similar to java in this regard.  Use `userTxt.Equals("user")`